# Bootstrap Carousel Not Working loaded from CDN

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was a web designer in the past, but it's been a few years since I've touched any code. I imagine I'm making a simple error, but I can't figure it out. I'm trying to include a bootstrap Testimonial Text Carousel, but it's not working. It does appear that jQuery and bootstrap.js is working, but carousel is not.

I'm attempting to make it super simple by using cdn's, as will just be a short term page. I've also chopped it all down to just the relevant portion of the page that isn't working. I often start removing pieces until something works to fins the issue, but i can't find it this time. Would greatly appreciate any help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Testimonial Test
    
    
    
        /* carousel */

```
    #quote-carousel {
        padding: 0 10px 30px 10px;
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
    /* indicator position */

    #quote-carousel .carousel-indicators {
        right: 50%;
        top: auto;
        bottom: -10px;
        margin-right: -19px;
    }
    /* indicator color */

    #quote-carousel .carousel-indicators li {
        background: #c0c0c0;
    }
    /* active indicator */

    #quote-carousel .carousel-indicators .active {
        background: #333333;
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 1px;
    }
</style>
```

```
<!-- FANS-->
<section id="fans">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="p-5">
                    <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle" src="img/fans.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 order-lg-1">
                <div class="p-5">
                    <h2 class="display-4">Fans</h2>

                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="quote-carousel">

                                    <!-- Bottom Carousel Indicators -->
                                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                        <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                        <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                        <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                                    </ol>

                                    <!-- Carousel Slides / Quotes -->
                                    <div class="carousel-inner">

                                        <!-- Quote 1 -->
                                        <div class="item active">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                    <p>&ldquo;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.&rdquo;</p>
                                                    <small><strong>Vulputate M., Dolor</strong></small>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <!-- Quote 2 -->
                                        <div class="item">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                    <p>&ldquo;Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum.&rdquo;</p>
                                                    <small><strong>Fringilla A., Vulputate Sit</strong></small>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <!-- Quote 3 -->
                                        <div class="item">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                    <p>&ldquo;Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.&rdquo;</p>
                                                    <small><strong>Aenean A., Justo Cras</strong></small>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //carousel options
        $('#quote-carousel').carousel({
            pause: true,
            interval: 10000,
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Did you include bootstraps css?

Comment: Yes, for some reason it got cut from the code on the when posting.

Comment: <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class name for carousel items is `carousel-item` and not `item`.
So you should change every

```
<div class="item"> ...
```

into

```
<div class="carousel-item">
```

---

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/486ehc8j/)

[Carousel Reference - Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/)

Comment: That did the trick! I had been following this example: https://codepen.io/danielmdesigns/pen/yNzJwB which had just "item" vs. "carousel-item". Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: The example is actually correct, in Bootstrap 3 the class name was `item`, it was changed to `carousel-item` in Bootstrap 4! (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#carousel)

Comment: I had looked for some discrepancies between 3 and 4, because i anticipated that to be the issue, but totally missed that. Thanks again for the help!